# Как сделать чтоб блоки переключались?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть такой блок. Нужно чтоб при нажатии на верхние элементы менялось описание. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Есть отличный пример с кодом [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
    var blok = document.getElementsByClassName('blok');
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

    for (let i=0;i<blok.length;i++){
        blok[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            for(let z=0;z<text.length;z++){
                text[z].style.display = "none";
            }
            text[i].style.display = "block";
        })
    }
```

```css
    .blok{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .text{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="blok">Блок 1</div><div class="blok">Блок 2</div><div class="blok">Блок 3</div><div class="blok">Блок 4</div><div class="blok">Блок 5</div>
<div class="text">Текст 1</div>
<div class="text">Текст 2</div>
<div class="text">Текст 3</div>
<div class="text">Текст 4</div>
<div class="text">Текст 5</div>
```